# Creating views for a Django application to return object data as JSON & JSONP

Tags: python, json, django

I'm trying to create views for my django application to utilize models I've created beforehand. The models are the continents/countries of the world and the views are meant to return stringified data of them, depending on what has been called.

The views are either called to return JSON/JSONP -formatted data, and either data related to a single country or data related to a continent.

I'm trying to create the view for a single country first, but I'm not entirely sure if what I'm doing is exactly correct.

def country_json(request, continent_code, country_code):

```
country = Country(code = country_code)
country.save()
obj = json.dumps(country.__dict__)

return HttpResponse(obj, content_type="application/json")
```

I have to figure out a way to check whether I have to return as JSON/JSONP, but I think it should be somewhat simple by viewing the request (check if the request has callback?), but I'm not entirely sure if what I've got here now works even for what I want to achieve at this stage.

The model for a country looks like

```
   class Country(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='', unique=True)
code = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='', unique=True)
continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent, default='', related_name='countries')

def __init__(self):
    self.area = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    self.population = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    self.capital = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='')

def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s %s %s %s %s' % (self.name, self.code, self.capital, self.population, self.area, self.continent)

class Meta:
    ordering = ["name"]
    verbose_name_plural = "countries"
```

and the json / jsonp that the view should return would look like something like this (examples)

json:

```
{
  "area": 337030,
  "population": 5244000,
  "capital": "Helsinki"
}
```

jsonp:

```
myCallbackFunction({
  "area": 337030,
  "population": 5244000,
  "capital": "Helsinki"
})
```

- Is there any established way to test out how my view works, to see what kind of data it tries to return?
- Is this a good start to what I'm trying to achieve, or are there some bad/wrong practices?

Edit:

This view seems to more or less work single country JSON, but now I have to add another branch to convert it to JSONP if I need to

```
def country_json(request, continent_code, country_code):
    all_countries = Country.objects.all()
    for country in all_countries:
        if country.code == country_code:
            area = country.area
            population = country.population
            capital = country.capital           
            dictionary = dict([('area', area), ('population', population), ('capital', capital)])
            obj = json.dumps(dictionary, indent=4)
            return HttpResponse(obj, content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: Your code is a very odd mix of Python and JavaScript, which won't work in either language. Nevertheless, the proper way to do this sort of thing is to use [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org).

Comment: If I wanted to use dumps instead, where should I start or what can I read up on it?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Ideally I want to be able to jsonify it with something like `country = Country(code = country_code)
country.save()
obj = json.dumps(country.__dict__)` , I edited the question's code to reflect this attempt

The reason is that I probably don't want to include any additional libraries/etc if I can avoid it

Comment: Why don't you use JSONResponse instead of HttpResponse? And while you don't want to use Django Rest Framework I suggest you have a look at its features

Answer (score 0):

This works for both JSON and JSONP, but I had no good way to test it apart from built up test functions specifically made for this.

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json

from .models import Continent, Country


def continent_json(request, continent_code):
    all_continents = Continent.objects.all()
    my_dictionary = {}
    for continent in all_continents:
        if continent.code == continent_code:
            for country in continent.countries.all():
                my_dictionary[country.code] = country.name
            response = JsonResponse(my_dictionary)
            response.status_code = 200
            callback = request.GET.get('callback')
            if not callback:
                return HttpResponse(response, content_type="application/json")        
            response =  '{0}({1})'.format(callback, response)
            return HttpResponse(response, content_type="application/javascript")

    raise Http404("Not implemented")

def country_json(request, continent_code, country_code):
    all_countries = Country.objects.all()
    for country in all_countries:
        if country.code == country_code:
            if country.continent.code == continent_code:
                area = country.area
                population = country.population
                capital = country.capital           
                dictionary = dict([('area', area), ('population', population), ('capital', capital)])
                obj = json.dumps(dictionary, indent=4)
                response = JsonResponse(dictionary)
                response.status_code = 200  
                callback = request.GET.get('callback')
                if not callback:
                    return HttpResponse(response, content_type="application/json")
                response =  '{0}({1})'.format(callback, response)
                return HttpResponse(response, content_type="application/javascript")

    raise Http404()
```